# Fastest Way to copy data from table on one sheet to specific spots on another with VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a table of information on one sheet. I have a calculator on another sheet where I load the data, make changes and save back to the table.

There are now over 60 columns of data that is stored within the table that needs to be recalled into the calculator.  When it was only 10 or 15 columns, it was pretty fast.  Now, it takes a while to load/reset/save data and I am continuously adding to it.

I have 2 activex buttons, Load and Save

When loading the data into the calculator, the code looks like:
Where dat is the row of the table the record is on referenced earlier in the code.

```
Range("QQ_Phone1").Value = DD.Cells(dat, 5)
Range("QQ_Phone2").Value = DD.Cells(dat, 6)
Range("QQ_Email").Value = DD.Cells(dat, 7)
Range("QQ_Email2").Value = DD.Cells(dat, 8)
```

When Saving the data the code looks like:

```
DD.Cells(dat, 5) = Range("QQ_Phone1").Value
DD.Cells(dat, 6) = Range("QQ_Phone2").Value
DD.Cells(dat, 7) = Range("QQ_Email").Value
DD.Cells(dat, 8) = Range("QQ_Email2").Value
```

The header row of the columns match the names of the cells where the data should go on the other sheet.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this? For example, make an array of the entire row where the data is, and then fill the named cells with the data in only a few lines of code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not doing it already, try using:

1. [`Application.ScreenUpdating`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating)

   > Turn screen updating off to speed up your macro code. You won't be
   >   able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.

   At the begining of your code turn screen updating to false: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

   And turn it back on at the end of your code: `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`
2. [`Application.Calculation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculation)

   > Whenever you update a cell, Excel goes through a process to recalculate the workbook. When working directly within Excel you want this to happen 99.9% of the time (the exception being if you are working with an extremely large workbook). However, this can really slow down your VBA code. It’s a good practice to set your calculations to manual at the begining of macros and restore calculations at the end of macros. If you need to recalculate the workbook you can manually tell Excel to calculate.

   Again, turn it to manual at the beginning: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

   And turn it back to automatic at the end: `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`

   If you need to recalculate formulas in your code (for example to copy proper, recalculated values) use `calculate`

   [See more here.](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/on-off-calculations/)

Comment: Thank you!  I am going to try this and let you know.  But other then that, am I copying the code the right way?  There isn't a better way to copy the data?

Comment: Adding those 4 lines of code made a huge difference!  From 11-12seconds down to 2 or 3 seconds!.  Thank you